# Rails run with puma in dockerfile and enable https

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, http, https

This is an example of a Dockerfile for ruby on rails project.
I want to run it with ssl key and cert

```
RUN apt-get update -yqq && apt-get install -y npm && npm install -g yarn
RUN apt-get install -y ruby-full
RUN apt install libsqlite3-dev
RUN gem install rails --version=6.1
RUN mkdir /var/app
WORKDIR /var/app
COPY . .
RUN bundle install --without development test

RUN npm install --force
RUN export SECRET_KEY_BASE=...............................
EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 8443
RUN rails webpacker:install
#RUN rake assets:clean
RUN rake assets:precompile
CMD rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -e production
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
FROM ruby:3.0.2
RUN apt-get update -yqq && apt-get install -y npm && npm install -g yarn
RUN apt-get install -y ruby-full
RUN apt install libsqlite3-dev
RUN gem install rails --version=6.1
RUN mkdir /var/app
WORKDIR /var/app
COPY . .
RUN bundle install --without development test

RUN npm install --force
RUN export SECRET_KEY_BASE=...............................
EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 8443
RUN rails webpacker:install
#RUN rake assets:clean
RUN rake assets:precompile
CMD puma -b 'ssl://0.0.0.0:8443?key=yourkey.key&cert=yourcertificat.pem&verify_mode=none' -b 'tcp://0.0.0.0:80' -e production
```

In config/environment/production.rb add: `config.force_ssl=true`

You can you freessl to get ssl key and certificat for your domain;
https://freessl.org/
To run it on you virtual machine or instance: `docker run -d -p 443:443 -p 80:80 yourimage:tag`